# Want to store name/value pairs in a single string column, how can I do this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to store name/value pairs in the database.

I want to then want to pull those name/value pairs from the db and loop through them and output something like:

```
nvpairs.each do |k,v|

  puts k, v

end
```

I want this to be as fast as possible (de-serializing it when loading the rows from the db into the model's property or if I do it manually from the string model property), what options do I have?

Comment: In general, this is not such a hot idea. What if the key ends with (or the value starts with) the delimiter?

Comment: Any particular reason that you want to store them in a single column rather than an association table?

Comment: @mu I don't want this to be an expensive call, its a popular query and no need to get complicated with it with db tables etc.  scenario calls for very a performant implementation.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You're worried about performance, throwing buzzwords around like "performant implmentation", but don't know how to code this?

Comment: The fastest approach will almost certainly be a association table in the database, you're probably not going to be able to out-perform a database at wrangling data (let alone be as reliable); databases manage data, that's what they do and they do it well. Furthermore, "high performance" and "complicated tables" are not mutually exclusive and I'd hardly call a single association table complicated. And, as usual, naive guesses mean nothing where performance is concerned, only multiple profiled implementations matter.

Answer (score 1):

Retrieving strings containing the name/value pairs encoded, then decoding them for further processing, will probably be slower than retrieving the name and value fields separately and processing them.

Databases are really fast at grabbing rows when there is no where clause. Simple where clauses are almost as fast. If you need real speed, then write a DBI-based SQL query. If you don't need that much speed, then write the raw SQL yourself and stuff it into an ORM query. If that's too much work then I start questioning the need-for-speed claim and think ActiveRecord or any ORM will suffice because they generate good SQL for simple lookups. And, at that point you'd be on top of all the records extremely fast.

Sounds to me like you need to do a benchmark.

Comment: I think you forgot the "get off my lawn part" :)

Answer (score 0):

Come up with a hash-to-string encoding/decoding method.

For example, you could use commas to separate key/values and semicolons to separate pairs; just make sure that any control characters can be escaped if they are part of the content (e.g. use "`\`" to escape commas, semicolons and backslashes which are actually part of a key/value).  For example:

```
h = {1 => 2, '3,4' => '5;6', 7 => '8\9'}
s = encode_hash(h) # => "1,2;3\\,4,5\\;6;7,8\\9"
d = decode_hash(s) # => {"1" => "2", "3,4" => "5;6", "7" => "8\\9"}
```

Performance will depend greatly on your implementation but, of course, native modules are easy to write and can yield excellent results.

Comment: JSON works fine for what it's designed to do. If you needed to throw a big predetermined structure out the wire as JSON then it *might* make sense to pre-encode as JSON.

Comment: JSON might be fine for your needs, the only way to know is to try it and benchmark it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Rails Serialization :

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Serialization.html

http://jqr.github.com/2009/02/01/making-rails-serialize-even-better.html